# $C =e^{10^{-4}(-x^2-2y^2)}$ path using calculus or directional derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]
My work:

I guess directional derivative has to do something with it.
i an find the $$\nabla C $$ but how to find the direction of maximum increase ?
Concentration is from the source and shark position is somewhere else.

How to get path from ppm ?? ppm is chemistry hahaha. I hate it
Furthermore it states 2 methods to solve.

Can you give me hints of the methods and let me know what do I need to find. I can try on my own. Please do comment